# How to apply class="active" to filter in the same view with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<dl class="sub-nav" text-align="center">
<dt>Filter:</dt>
<dd class="active"><a href="http://localhost:9000/#/">New</a></dd>                                                
<dd><a href="http://localhost:9000/#/ignored">Ignored</a></dd>                                            
<dd><a href="http://localhost:9000/#/alerted">Alerted</a></dd>
```

This is what I have, and I need class="active" to move down depending on the URL. The problem is that everything uses the same view, but different controllers. How can I go about doing this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much more about your controllers or routes, one way you can do this is when setting up your `$routeProvider` you could specify additional route data and use `ngClass`

```
.when("/ignored", {
    //stuff
    action : "ignored"
})
```

And in your controller inject `$route`

```
function MyCtrl(//stuff $route){
    $scope.$route = $route;
}
```

And your view

```
<dl class="sub-nav" text-align="center">
<dt>Filter:</dt>
<dd ng-class="{'active' : $route.current.action == 'home'}">
    <a href="http://localhost:9000/#/">New</a>
</dd>                                                
<dd ng-class="{'active' : $route.current.action == 'ignored'}">
    <a href="http://localhost:9000/#/ignored">Ignored</a>
</dd>                                        
<dd ng-class="{'active' : $route.current.action == 'alerted'}">
    <a href="http://localhost:9000/#/alerted">Alerted</a>
</dd>
```